# "Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid data found when processing input"

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I am using ffmpeg to convert a RTSP stream to a RTMP stream. The RMTP stream will then be feeded into Wowza Streaming Engine. I have no ideas why it works very good in one server but fails in another server. Both servers are in different networks but both are Window Server 2012 ,have the same ffmpeg version, convert a same RTSP stream , but one fails with the error message **Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid data found when processing input**

The ffmpeg command I used is :

```
ffmpeg -v debug -r 7 -i "rtsp://rtsp-stream-source-server/someRtspStream" -frame rate 7 -video_size 800x592 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 750k -bufsize 1500k -tune zerolatency -g 14 -an -r 7 -f flv rtmp://wowza-server:1935/app/stream1
```

I compare both ffmpeg debug messages in both cases and notice the followings differences / behaviours :

1. For the success case, ffmpeg first open RTSP stream using UDP, but UDP timeout, then it retries with TCP .For the failure case , it seems that it success with UDP and no need to retry with TCP.
2. When ffmpeg successfully open a RTSP stream ,the following information is printed out for the success case

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://rtsp-stream-source-server/someRtspStream':
  Metadata:
    title           : Unnamed
    comment         : N/A
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.151889, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 53, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, center), 800x600 (800x608) [SAR 1:1 DA
R 4:3], 0/1, 6.58 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
```

And for the failure case , the following information is printed out :

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://rtsp-stream-source-server/someRtspStream':
  Metadata:
    title           : Unnamed
    comment         : N/A
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.151944, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 28, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, center), 800x600 (800x608) [SAR 1:1 DA
R 4:3], 0/1, 6.67 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
```

Please note that the number after "Stream #0:0" is different.

3. In the "Stream mapping" process , the failure case has the following error messages .Then ffmpeg process stops:

```
detected 4 logical cores
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] sps_id 0 out of range
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid data found when processing input
```

Do you have any ideas for the failure cases and how can I troubleshoot it?

Below is the debug message for both cases for the information

#### Failure Case

```
Opening an input file: rtsp://rtsp-stream-source-server/someRtspStream.
[tcp @ 00000000004b8740] No default whitelist set
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] SDP:
v=0
o=- 1509095634684735 1 IN IP4 192.168.63.139
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.08.20
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:Unnamed
a=x-qt-text-inf:N/A
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:15000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=control:track1

Failed to parse interval end specification ''
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] video codec set to: h264
[rtp @ 00000000004b8b40] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000000004ba420] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000000004ba420] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 00000000004ba420] end receive buffer size reported is 65536
[udp @ 0000000001c3d160] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0000000001c3d160] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000000001c3d160] end receive buffer size reported is 65536
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] hello state=0
Failed to parse interval end specification ''
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] sps_id 0 out of range
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 00000000004bd160] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Reinit context to 800x608, pix_fmt: yuvj420p
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] nal_unit_type: 0, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000004b8d40] Unknown NAL code: 0 (0 bits)
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] All info found
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] rfps: 6.500000 0.018292
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] rfps: 6.583333 0.006178
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] rfps: 6.666667 0.004542
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] rfps: 6.750000 0.013386
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] rfps: 13.250000 0.016201
[rtsp @ 0000000001c2ba00] rfps: 13.333333 0.018170
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://rtsp-stream-source-server/someRtspStream':
  Metadata:
    title           : Unnamed
    comment         : N/A
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.151944, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 28, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, center), 800x600 (800x608) [SAR 1:1 DA
R 4:3], 0/1, 6.67 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url rtmp://wowza-server:1935/app/stream1.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument libx264.
Applying option an (disable audio) with argument 1.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 7.
Applying option f (force format) with argument flv.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: rtmp://wowza-server:1935/app/stream1.
[rtmp @ 00000000023c0ec0] No default whitelist set
Parsing...
Parsed protocol: 0
Parsed host    : 127.0.0.1
Parsed app     : vdc
RTMP_Connect1, ... connected, handshaking
HandShake: Type Answer   : 03
HandShake: Server Uptime : 96850052
HandShake: FMS Version   : 3.0.1.1
HandShake: Handshaking finished....
RTMP_Connect1, handshaked
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=88
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 58 14  00 00 00 00               ......X.....
  0000:  02 00 07 63 6f 6e 6e 65  63 74 00 3f f0 00 00 00   ...connect.?....
  0010:  00 00 00 03 00 03 61 70  70 02 00 03 76 64 63 00   ......app...vdc.
  0020:  04 74 79 70 65 02 00 0a  6e 6f 6e 70 72 69 76 61   .type...nonpriva
  0030:  74 65 00 05 74 63 55 72  6c 02 00 19 72 74 6d 70   te..tcUrl...rtmp
  0040:  3a 2f 2f 31 32 37 2e 30  2e 30 2e 31 3a 31 39 33   ://127.0.0.1:193
  0050:  35 2f 76 64 63 00 00 09                            5/vdc...
Invoking connect
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 04 05  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 26 25 a0                                        .&%.
HandleServerBW: server BW = 2500000
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 05 06  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 26 25 a0 02                                     .&%..
HandleClientBW: client BW = 2500000 2
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 06 04  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 00 00 00 00 00                                  ......
HandleCtrl, received ctrl. type: 0, len: 6
HandleCtrl, Stream Begin 0
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 04 01  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 00 02 00                                        ....
HandleChangeChunkSize, received: chunk size change to 512
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 01 05 14  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 07 5f 72 65 73 75  6c 74 00 3f f0 00 00 00   ..._result.?....
  0010:  00 00 00 03 00 06 66 6d  73 56 65 72 02 00 0e 46   ......fmsVer...F
  0020:  4d 53 2f 33 2c 35 2c 37  2c 37 30 30 39 00 0c 63   MS/3,5,7,7009..c
  0030:  61 70 61 62 69 6c 69 74  69 65 73 00 40 3f 00 00   apabilities.@?..
  0040:  00 00 00 00 00 04 6d 6f  64 65 00 3f f0 00 00 00   ......mode.?....
  0050:  00 00 00 00 00 09 03 00  05 6c 65 76 65 6c 02 00   .........level..
  0060:  06 73 74 61 74 75 73 00  04 63 6f 64 65 02 00 1d   .status..code...
  0070:  4e 65 74 43 6f 6e 6e 65  63 74 69 6f 6e 2e 43 6f   NetConnection.Co
  0080:  6e 6e 65 63 74 2e 53 75  63 63 65 73 73 00 0b 64   nnect.Success..d
  0090:  65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69  6f 6e 02 00 15 43 6f 6e   escription...Con
  00a0:  6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 20  73 75 63 63 65 65 64 65   nection succeede
  00b0:  64 2e 00 04 64 61 74 61  08 00 00 00 00 00 07 76   d...data.......v
  00c0:  65 72 73 69 6f 6e 02 00  0a 33 2c 35 2c 37 2c 37   ersion...3,5,7,7
  00d0:  30 30 39 00 00 09 00 08  63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 64   009.....clientid
  00e0:  00 41 d6 2d 2b 68 80 00  00 00 0e 6f 62 6a 65 63   .A.-+h.....objec
  00f0:  74 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e  67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   tEncoding.......
  0100:  00 00 00 00 09                                     .....
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 261 bytes
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
(object end)
Property: 
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
(object begin)
Property: 
(object end)
Property: 
Property: 
(object end)
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking 
HandleInvoke, received result for method call 
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=33
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 21 14                            C.....!.
  0000:  02 00 0d 72 65 6c 65 61  73 65 53 74 72 65 61 6d   ...releaseStream
  0010:  00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 05 02 00 04 6e 74 74   .@...........ntt
  0020:  31                                                 1
Invoking releaseStream
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=29
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 1d 14                            C.......
  0000:  02 00 09 46 43 50 75 62  6c 69 73 68 00 40 08 00   ...FCPublish.@..
  0010:  00 00 00 00 00 05 02 00  04 6e 74 74 31            .........ntt1
Invoking FCPublish
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=25
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 19 14                            C.......
  0000:  02 00 0c 63 72 65 61 74  65 53 74 72 65 61 6d 00   ...createStream.
  0010:  40 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  05                        @........
Invoking createStream
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 88 14  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 0b 6f 6e 46 43 50  75 62 6c 69 73 68 00 00   ...onFCPublish..
  0010:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05  03 00 05 6c 65 76 65 6c   ...........level
  0020:  02 00 06 73 74 61 74 75  73 00 04 63 6f 64 65 02   ...status..code.
  0030:  00 17 4e 65 74 53 74 72  65 61 6d 2e 50 75 62 6c   ..NetStream.Publ
  0040:  69 73 68 2e 53 74 61 72  74 00 0b 64 65 73 63 72   ish.Start..descr
  0050:  69 70 74 69 6f 6e 02 00  19 46 43 50 75 62 6c 69   iption...FCPubli
  0060:  73 68 20 74 6f 20 73 74  72 65 61 6d 20 6e 74 74   sh to stream ntt
  0070:  31 2e 00 08 63 6c 69 65  6e 74 69 64 00 41 d6 2d   1...clientid.A.-
  0080:  2b 68 80 00 00 00 00 09                            +h......
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 136 bytes
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: NULL
Property: 
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
(object end)
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking 
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 1d 14  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 07 5f 72 65 73 75  6c 74 00 40 10 00 00 00   ..._result.@....
  0010:  00 00 00 05 00 3f f0 00  00 00 00 00 00            .....?.......
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 29 bytes
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: NULL
Property: 
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking 
HandleInvoke, received result for method call 
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=34
  0000:  04 00 00 00 00 00 22 14  01 00 00 00               ......".....
  0000:  02 00 07 70 75 62 6c 69  73 68 00 40 14 00 00 00   ...publish.@....
  0010:  00 00 00 05 02 00 04 6e  74 74 31 02 00 04 6c 69   .......ntt1...li
  0020:  76 65                                              ve
Invoking publish
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 06 04  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 00 00 00 00 01                                  ......
HandleCtrl, received ctrl. type: 0, len: 6
HandleCtrl, Stream Begin 1
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=516
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 7c 14  01 00 00 00               ......|.....
  0000:  02 00 08 6f 6e 53 74 61  74 75 73 00 00 00 00 00   ...onStatus.....
  0010:  00 00 00 00 05 03 00 05  6c 65 76 65 6c 02 00 06   ........level...
  0020:  73 74 61 74 75 73 00 04  63 6f 64 65 02 00 17 4e   status..code...N
  0030:  65 74 53 74 72 65 61 6d  2e 50 75 62 6c 69 73 68   etStream.Publish
  0040:  2e 53 74 61 72 74 00 0b  64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74   .Start..descript
  0050:  69 6f 6e 02 00 10 50 75  62 6c 69 73 68 69 6e 67   ion...Publishing
  0060:  20 6e 74 74 31 2e 00 08  63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 64    ntt1...clientid
  0070:  00 41 d6 2d 2b 68 80 00  00 00 00 09               .A.-+h......
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 124 bytes
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: NULL
Property: 
(object begin)
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
Property: 
(object end)
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking 
HandleInvoke, onStatus: NetStream.Publish.Start
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000001c2a9a0] sps_id 0 out of range
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid data found when processing input
[AVIOContext @ 000000000239a360] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=31
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 1f 14                            C.......
  0000:  02 00 0b 46 43 55 6e 70  75 62 6c 69 73 68 00 40   ...FCUnpublish.@
  0010:  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 05  02 00 04 6e 74 74 31      ...........ntt1
Invoking FCUnpublish
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=516, size=34
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 22 14                            C.....".
  0000:  02 00 0c 64 65 6c 65 74  65 53 74 72 65 61 6d 00   ...deleteStream.
  0010:  40 1c 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00   @.........?.....
  0020:  00 00                                              ..
Invoking deleteStream
```

Comment: It looks like the RTSP stream contains different data in UDP compared to TCP, for whatever reason, and the UDP data seems to be bad. You can try to [force always TCP](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp), and see if that fixes it.